# Erro ao usar while em função de gerar código de barras

Tags: php, imagem, loop, while, código-de-barras

Primeiro:

Estou usando a função abaixo e estou implementando um chile.

Motivo: preciso gerar vários códigos,exemplo: 1 2 3 4 5 .... 98 99 100,segue código:

```
<?php
 $i = 1;
while ($i <= 100) {

    function geraCodigoBarra($numero){
        $fino = 1;
        $largo = 3;
        $altura = 70;

        $barcodes[0] = '00110';
        $barcodes[1] = '10001';
        $barcodes[2] = '01001';
        $barcodes[3] = '11000';
        $barcodes[4] = '00101';
        $barcodes[5] = '10100';
        $barcodes[6] = '01100';
        $barcodes[7] = '00011';
        $barcodes[8] = '10010';
        $barcodes[9] = '01010';

        for($f1 = 9; $f1 >= 0; $f1--){
            for($f2 = 9; $f2 >= 0; $f2--){
                $f = ($f1*10)+$f2;
                $texto = '';
                for($i = 1; $i < 6; $i++){
                    $texto .= substr($barcodes[$f1], ($i-1), 1).substr($barcodes[$f2] ,($i-1), 1);
                }
                $barcodes[$f] = $texto;
            }
        }

        echo '<img src="imagens/p.gif" width="'.$fino.'" height="'.$altura.'" border="0" />';
        echo '<img src="imagens/b.gif" width="'.$fino.'" height="'.$altura.'" border="0" />';
        echo '<img src="imagens/p.gif" width="'.$fino.'" height="'.$altura.'" border="0" />';
        echo '<img src="imagens/b.gif" width="'.$fino.'" height="'.$altura.'" border="0" />';

        echo '<img ';

        $texto = $numero;

        if((strlen($texto) % 2) <> 0){
            $texto = '0'.$texto;
        }

        while(strlen($texto) > 0){
            $i = round(substr($texto, 0, 2));
            $texto = substr($texto, strlen($texto)-(strlen($texto)-2), (strlen($texto)-2));

            if(isset($barcodes[$i])){
                $f = $barcodes[$i];
            }

            for($i = 1; $i < 11; $i+=2){
                if(substr($f, ($i-1), 1) == '0'){
                    $f1 = $fino ;
                }else{
                    $f1 = $largo ;
                }

                echo 'src="imagens/p.gif" width="'.$f1.'" height="'.$altura.'" border="0">';
                echo '<img ';

                if(substr($f, $i, 1) == '0'){
                    $f2 = $fino ;
                }else{
                    $f2 = $largo ;
                }

                echo 'src="imagens/b.gif" width="'.$f2.'" height="'.$altura.'" border="0">';
                echo '<img ';
            }
        }
        echo 'src="imagens/p.gif" width="'.$largo.'" height="'.$altura.'" border="0" />';
        echo '<img src="imagens/b.gif" width="'.$fino.'" height="'.$altura.'" border="0" />';
        echo '<img src="imagens/p.gif" width="1" height="'.$altura.'" border="0" />';
        echo'<br>';
        echo'<br>';
        echo"EAN: $i";
    }

    geraCodigoBarra('$i');

    echo $i++;

    }
?>
```

Segue retorno:

> EAN: 111 Fatal error: Cannot redeclare geraCodigoBarra() (previously
>   declared in C:\xampp\htdocs\cb\index.php:10) in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\cb\index.php on line 10

Segundo:
 Após gerar esses códigos,é possível exporta-los separadamente para .jpg ?para uma pasta determinada?, se sim como poderia fazer.

Para finalizar:

Preciso que o código seja de 13 números,como emplemento em meu código para ele acrescentar zeros e transformar, exemplo: `1` em `0000000000001`

Comment: De onde vem $numero?

Comment: Já que está usando PHP, talvez fosse melhor usar a biblioteca GD e fazer as barras numa imagem só. Está fora do que foi perguntado, mas o algoritmo de barras 2 de 5 dá pra ser bem simplificado também.

Comment: Seria bom não misturar várias dúvidas de natureza diferente na mesma pergunta. Costuma ser mais eficaz é perguntar em separado, resolvendo um problema por vez e passando para o próximo em outra postagem. Isto facilita para quem responde, permite que pessoas diferentes com conhecimentos específicos cuidem melhor de cada assunto, e diminui a chance de fechamento por amplitude.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amigo, a função geraCodigoBarra($numero) ela precisa estar fora do while, pois por ser um loop, ele esta processando repetidas vezes por isso o erro dizendo que você não pode redeclarar a função (Cannot redeclare).

```
<?php
function geraCodigoBarra($numero){
// seu codigo aqui
}


$i = 1;
while ($i <= 100) {

// processa a funcao
geraCodigoBarra('$i');

echo $i++;

}
?>
```

Referente as suas questões, acesse o manual em: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/ e faça a busca pelas funções que passo abaixo:

Referente a criação de imagem use a função:

imagecreate

Para salvar na pasta, use funções de manipulação de arquivos:

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.filesystem.php

- mkdir - cria o diretorio
- fopen - para criar o arquivo
- file_put_contents - para escrever os dados da imagem no arquivo
- fclose - fecha o arquivo que voce escreveu

Sobre o tamanho que precisa de saída, veja a função str_pad .

Obs: tudo que você precisa você encontra no Google, da uma buscada, mas os links que passei são do manual, fácil de fazer. Mas existem classes prontas que gerar códigos de barras já com funções de salvar como você quer.

Comment: Perfeito,ajudou muito,Obrigado.